# Lógica de programação - Constante

Tags: lógica

Se eu criar uma variável `int x = 10` e não altera-la durante todo o código ela é considerada uma constante? ou só é considerada uma constante se eu utilizar uma palavra reservada da linguagem por exemplo: `final int x = 10 (java)`

Comment: Uma pergunta adicional para deixar a pergunta mais complicada: **O compilador pode transformar uma variável em uma constante?**

Answer (score 3):

Ela não é uma constante, para ser, ela não poderia ser alterada de forma alguma.

Apesar de, como você colocou no exemplo, ela não ser alterada durante o código, ainda assim ela não é uma contante, porque a qualquer momento pode ser alterada.

Seria semelhante a dizer que um membro qualquer da classe é declarado `public`, mas por nunca ter sido usado fora da classe, ser considerado `private`.

Answer (score 2):

Nesse seu caso **matematicamente**, é sim uma constante.
Uma vez que um valor `x` não sofre alteração ao decorrer de uma linha de tempo ele é considerado uma constante, porém, quando fazemos um paralelo com a linguagem de programação *Java*(citado na pergunta) essa resposta não é a mesma. Nos sabemos que existe uma [keyword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords) `final`, que simplificando pra você, ela faz com que a variável possua um valor inalterável, dando mais excelência ao seu código/objetivo e sentido ao conceito de constante.

Comment: Só porque dentro do seu bloco de código a variável não sofre modificação não significa que ela chegará ao final de seu bloco de código inalterada. Exemplo: Uma variável publica declarada em biblioteca, dentro da biblioteca pode não existir um código sequer que altere o valor dessa variável mas um usuário externo dessa biblioteca pode fazer alterações arbitrárias em seu valor. A declaração de constante não é uma simplificação,  a declaração de constante é um contrato de que aquele elemento não terá seu valor alterado por via interna ou externa ao seu software.

Comment: Neste caso houve uma **alteração**, mesmo sendo de um "usuário externo". Por isso, que deixei bem claro que **em teoria** e **matematicamente** é uma constante, uma vez que seu valor não irá mudar: `que não muda; inalterável, invariável, fixo.`. Você citou um caso expecífico onde a variável publica teria seu valor alterado. É uma questão de ponto de vista. Porém, levando o assunto à *programação*, não é uma constante.

Comment: Eu citei um caso, mas posso citar mais três casos: Um Thread paralelo ao seu código pode alterar o valor da variável, um processo em pipe pode alterar o valor da variável ou um deamon instalado no sistema pode manipular esse valor. O valor de uma variável é imprevisível.

Comment: Não é que eu queira ser chato ou implicante com um conceito. É que eu já perdi dinheiro confiando na previsibilidade de variáveis.

Comment: Concordo totalmente contigo cara, e dando ênfase à minha linha de pensamento na resposta, quis demonstrar que matematicamente, é uma constante sim e com razão, porém, no mundo da programação sabemos que o desuso do `final` impede da realização desse conceito!

Comment: Fiz uma alteração e acredito que ficou mais claro o que eu quis passar em resposta, agradeço o feedback @AugustoVasques ✌️